# CSP Errors Help - Refused to frame 'REDACTED' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: html, content-security-policy

On my Website ive started to see all the widgets have gone and this error,

> Refused to frame 'WEBSITE_URL' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

and this:

> Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.ywxi.net/js/1.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Any idea how i could get this working using meta tags? Im using OpenLiteSpeed as a web server, and this is Express EJS

Comment: a peice of good old code would be very usefull to help us help you

Comment: Hey, what code do you need i dont have any CSP Code the ones ive tried and failed are:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'">
```


```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' https://URL/* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://cdn.ywxi.net/js/1.js 'unsafe-inline'" />
```

Comment: I'm guessing the content of the iframe is a third party site not under your control, is that right?  If so, it stopped working because they've added CSP rules specifically to prevent people from doing what you're doing.  Adding CSP tags to your own site will control whether other people can frame *your* site, it won't grant you access to theirs.     If ywxi.net is under your control then that's where you need to be adding the CSP rules to allow you to frame it from a different domain.

Comment: But thats a site widget that is only for a site, i know what you mean they can disable people using the sites with iframes but they wouldnt do that as thats what the service is for....

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how i could get this working using meta tags?

Since you said implied, in a comment, that you don't have any CSP rules in your `<meta>` tags: You can't.

You need to locate the code (possibly in your server-side programming, possibly in your web server configuration, possibility in your edge server cache configuration) which is setting the `Content-Security-Policy` **HTTP response header** and change that.

HTTP headers trump `<meta>` tags.

Comment: Im using OpenLiteSpeed, and nowhere in the Virual Hosts or Listeners is there anywhere they are setting the headers since this is  really only the first couple of weeks using i will need to contact there support thanks for the support

Comment: Whats odd is that, any other site using the server shows everything fine and has no CSP Policy but this site without any other plugins just the Express Route shows it having CSP but then Static without Express using .html it works fine also so im really stuck here...